# Insert (push) multiple elements at multiple different positions at the same time

Tags: r, append

I like the `append` function in R:

```
L <- 1:4
append(L,5,3)
[1] 1 2 3 5 4
```

I was wondering if there was a function that worked like `append` but allowed the insertion of *multiple elements* at *multiple positions* at the same time?

```
L <- 1:100
elements <- letters[1:5]
positions <- c(17,28,50,65,80)
```

Something like:

```
append(L, elements, positions)
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely a duplicate. Awesome answers there

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: [Add a series of elements in different locations within a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105673/add-a-series-of-elements-in-different-locations-within-a-vector)

I don't think a function like `append(L, elements, positions)` exists, although it'd be cool.